# How can I locate the Cancel button with below mentioned properties through Selenium WebDriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

The button HTML is:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" type="button">Cancel</button>
```

I tried with Class name locator and link text as well, please help.

Comment: which webdriver you are using?

Comment: please share exact HTML here for answer

Comment: link text only applies for anchor <a> tags, I believe.  The correct answer is below, just thought I'd add why your link text attempt would not work.

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks for the info.. :)

Comment: @this_is_om_vm it is Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the button with either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget[type='button']"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget'][contains(text(),'Cancel')]"));
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much...it worked..actually I was so dumb that i didn't use xpath at all..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to locate the element using following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'ui-button ui-corner-all')]"));
```